# Symfony: refresh test database for phpunit testing with autoincrements reset on fixtures added

Tags: sqlite, symfony, phpunit, fixtures

I want to create a fresh in memory sqlite test database to run my test against every time I run bin/phpunit. The solutions I have found so far empty the test database, but when I add the fixtures, their ids start from the last autoincremnt before the wipe.

Answer (score 5):

For whomever faces this problem, I post a solution I figured out starting from here (https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-testing-symfony-apps-with-a-disposable-database/) and some investigation and trial and error:

**Doctrine conf**

```
#api/config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
        memory:  true
        charset: UTF8
```

**WebTestCaseWithDatabase**

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;
use Metadata\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class WebTestCaseWithDatabase extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var KernelBrowser
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @var SchemaTool
     */
    protected $schemaTool;

    /**
     * @var ClassMetadata[]
     */
    protected $metaData;


    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // This is tricky. You need to boot the kernel to create the DDBB.                   
        // But if you boot it with static::bootKernel(),                        
        // an error will be thrown if you create the client in your tests, 
        // because static::createClient() tries boot again the kernel.
        // That's why I create the client and boot the kernel only once here.
        $this->client = static::createClient();

        // Make sure we are in the test environment
        if ('test' !== self::$kernel->getEnvironment()) {
            throw new \LogicException('Tests cases with fresh database must be executed in the test environment');
        }
        // Get the entity manager from the service container
        $this->em = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

        // Run the schema update tool using our entity metadata
        $this->metaData = $this->em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
        $this->schemaTool = new SchemaTool($this->em);
        $this->schemaTool->updateSchema($this->metaData);
    }

    // Helper function to add fixtures
    public function addFixture($className)
    {
        $loader = new Loader();
        $loader->addFixture(new $className);

        $purger = new ORMPurger($this->em);
        $executor = new ORMExecutor($this->em, $purger);
        $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
    }

    // Trunkate the whole database on tearDown
    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        // Purge all the fixtures data when the tests are finished
        $purger = new ORMPurger($this->em);
        // Purger mode 2 truncates, resetting autoincrements
        $purger->setPurgeMode(2);
        $purger->purge();
    }
}
```

**ExampleTest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use App\DataFixtures\ExampleFixture;

class ExampleTest extends WebTestCaseWithDatabase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // Add whatever fixtures you need here
        $this->addFixture(ExampleFixture::class);
    }

    // Add your tests 
    public function test_something()
    {
        // test code
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a package to do this for you the [dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle](https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle) can do this automatically. Each test will be run against a fresh database.